# SQLite delete rows based on multiple columns

Tags: database, sqlite

im pretty new to SQLite hence asking this question!

I need to remove rows in a table so that I have the earliest occurence of column each unique value in column X(colour) based on column Y (time).

Basically i have this:

**test | colour | time(s)**
one  | Yellow | 8
one  | Red    | 6
one  | Yellow | 10
two  | Red    | 4

Which i want to remove rows so that is looks like:

**test | colour | time(s)**
one  | Yellow | 8
two  | Red    | 4

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To be clearer i need to retain the Earliest occurence in time that each colour occurred, regardless of the test.

EDIT: I can select the rows i want to keep by doing this:

select * from ( select * from COL_TABLE order by time desc) x group by colour;

which produces the desired result, but i want to remove what is not there in the result of the select.

EDIT: The following worked thanks to @JimmyB:

```
   DELETE FROM COL_TABLE WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM COL_TABLE t2 WHERE     COL_TABLE .colour = t2.colour AND COL_TABLE .test = t2.test AND COL_TABLE .time < t2.time )
```

Comment: And how to determine the first entry?

Comment: @juergend `MIN( time )` it seems.

Comment: `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM my_table t2 WHERE my_table.colour = t2.colour AND my_table.test = t2.test AND my_table.time < t2.time )`

Comment: @JimmyB unfortunatley that didnt work for me!

Comment: @juergend Its more that i need the Earliest occurence in time that each colour occurred

Comment: Does the table have some ID column?

Comment: it doesnt but it could be added. The table will be added to periodically with new rows and no way of tracking the ID between each update to the table.

Comment: @JimmyB after swapping the 1 to a * it worked! thanks!

Comment: Great. Elaborated and turned the comment into an answer now :)

Comment: @CL. In sqlite *every* table has a primary key; `rowid` if none is explicitly specified. See e.g. https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include subqueries (`EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`) in the `WHERE` clause of a `DELETE` statement.

Like subqueries in `SELECT`s, these can refer to the table in the outer statement to create matches.

In your case, try this:

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM my_table t2
  WHERE my_table.colour = t2.colour
  AND my_table.test = t2.test
  AND my_table.time < t2.time
)
```

This statement uses three noteworthy constructs:

- Subquery in `DELETE`
- Self-join
- Emulation of a `MIN(...)`, via self-join

The subquery with `EXISTS` is mentioned above.

The self-join is required whenever one row of a table must be compared against other rows of the same table. Finding the minimum value of some column is exactly that.

Normally, you'd use the `MIN(...)` function to find the minimum. The minimum can be defined as the single value for which no *lower* value exists, and that's what we're using here because we're not actually interested in the actual value but only want to identify the *record* which contains that value.

(Since we're deleting, our `SELECT` yields all the *non*-minimum rows, which we want to delete to keep only the minimums.)

So, what the statement says is:

Delete all records from `my_table` for which there is at least one record in `my_table` with the same `colour` and the same `test` but a *lower* `time`.